# How can I push address to dynamic array without duplication?

Tags: arrays

I'm developing a web application using Ethereum SmartContract.
And I have a question.

I want to add a address to array of addresses without duplication.
But I can't do without duplication.
It adds all address evenif array contains same value.
Below is code.

```
function addTokenHolder(address _tokenHolder) returns (bool success) {
  uint len = tokenHolders.length;
  for(uint i = 0; i > len; i++) {
    if (tokenHolders[i] == _tokenHolder) return false;
  }
  tokenHolders.push(_tokenHolder);
  return true;
}
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

What Max said about `>`.

*In my opinion*, it's usually best to shy away from `for` loops for this sort of thing. Each iteration will cost gas. The bigger the list, the higher the cost, so it won't scale; either because the transaction costs become unacceptable, or because the block gas limit is actually exceeded and the transaction can't run at any price.

Here's a scalable way using a mapping for random access. We're just setting a bit to note known addresses so we can avoid duplication.

This gives a flat cost for checking and inserting at any scale.

Hope it helps.

```
contract Unique {

    address[] public tokenHolders;

    // scalable way with no iteration

    mapping(address => bool) public tokenHolderKnown;

    function scalableAddTokenHolder(address tokenHolder) returns(bool succes) {
        if(!tokenHolderKnown[tokenHolder]) {
            tokenHolders.push(tokenHolder);
            tokenHolderKnown[tokenHolder] = true;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Update: Some simple storage patterns here: [Blog: Simple Storage Patterns in Solidity](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/blog-simple-storage-patterns-in-solidity)

Comment: +1, using mapping to simulate set is more efficient and idiomatic. Moreover, building code around mappings often allows to extract looping and iteration from contract to client side.

Comment: I'm so sorry for replying you.
Thank you very much.
I understood well!

Answer (score 0):

Your loop never loops because of the looping condition.

Try to reverse condition in `i > len`:

```
for(uint i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (tokenHolders[i] == _tokenHolder) return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code instead !

```
function addTokenHolder(address _tokenHolder) returns (bool success) {
  uint len = tokenHolders.length;
  for(uint i = 0; i < len; ) {
    if (tokenHolders[i] =! _tokenHolder) {
       revert("already exist");
     }
     else {
        tokenHolders.push(_tokenHolder);
      }
  }
  
  return true;
}
```